# Point to polygon walking distance

Tags: qgis, accessibility

I do a research on urban park accessibility. I am working with QGIS 3.4 and ORS-Tools for the distance calculation by foot. A use of ArcGIS is possible.

I use a point layer with geocoded apartements and a few polygon layers representing the parks.

I would like to calculate the walking distance with OpenRouteService (ORS-Tool) to the edge of the nearest park polygon. My latest research results concerning distance point to polygon have always led to the use oft the NNJOIN-Tool, which only calculates the euclidean distance to the nearest polygon.

My first attempt was to calculate the distance between the polygon centroids, representing the park and the apartments. After that I did a query (statistics by category) to filter the shortest distance. But for my research goal I need the distance to the egde of the closest polygon.

Answer (score 3):

**Convert your polygon boundaries to points. Calculate the distance from each apartment to the nearest point**

1. Use the `Densify` tool to add more vertices along the edges of your polygons.
2. Use the `Extract Vertices` tool to extract the vertices to a point layer.
3. Run your distance calculations using the vertex layer instead of the park polygons.